# for loop used multiple times with same parameter

Tags: python, variables, for-in-loop

Would python have a problem dealing with my re-use of `item` in various for-in loops???

```
list1 = (A,B,C,D)
list2 = (E,F,G,H)

for item in list1:
    (eg) ...item+5
    (eg) ...item*1

for item in list2:
    (eg) ...item+2
    (eg) ...item*3
```

Comment: This is a "Try It And See" question: What happened when you tried it? Did you experience a behavior that makes you suspect Python *would* have a problem with this? If so, what was that behavior? If not, what makes you ask?

Comment: haven't got to a stage where the script can be tested and counldn't bothered writing a mini-script to test it.
thought it would be quicker asking here than going back to re-do it all later ;)

Comment: You can test something like this quickly in a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) without disrupting any existing project. Just type `python` in a command prompt.

Comment: i've not been coding for long, aware of REPL techniques but obviously don't use it enough yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not have a problem with re-using names in `for` loops.

`item` will get rebound for each and every iteration, you can safely reuse it.